# Criar método parcial (partial) no C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, método, partial

Tem como criar um método similar a uma classe que é parcial?

Por exemplo:

Tem o método `$InitializeComponent()` que é da classe de um formulário.

Eu quero incrementar esta função, sem mexer na original (criar um *proxy*). Tem como eu fazer isso?

O que eu tentei e não seu certo foi:

```
partial class form1
{
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

partial class form1 : Form
{
     ...
     partial void InitializeComponent()
     {
           ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível, isto realmente se chama [*partial method*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/6b0scde8(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas talvez não faça o que você quer. Não dá para escrever uma parte do código do método em um lugar e uma parte em outro. O que dá para fazer é declarar o método em uma parte e definir o código dele em outra parte. Como é em C/C++.

Eu acho desnecessário realmente fazer isto mas se quer mesmo, se acha que tem um motivo real para fazer, o que você pode fazer é criar um método principal e chamar um outro auxiliar que está na outra parte. *Partial method* foi criado para facilitar o uso com geradores de código, para gerar a declaração e garantir que o programador vai criar a implementação em outro arquivo.

Método tem algoritmo, é diferente de uma classe que é uma estrutura de dados. Na estrutura de dados a posição onde está cada elemento não é muito importante. O compilador consegue se virar bem com isto.

Em um algoritmo esta parte do código vai entrar onde? O compilador não tem como saber qual vai primeiro, ou pior, se é para entrar no meio. Só o programador pode dizer como isto será feito. Então basta fazer uma chamada a outro método no local apropriado.

Se realmente quer fazer um proxy, faça um [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Eu ainda acho que você está tentando fazer uma gambiarra que ou não é possível ou não vai dar em boa coisa.

#### Arquivo1

```
partial class form1 {
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        ...
        InitializeComponentAux();
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Arquivo2

```
partial class form1 : Form {
     ...
     partial void InitializeComponentAux() {
           ...
     }
}
```

Com o *partial method* oficial só daria para fazer isto:

#### Arquivo1

```
partial class form1 {
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent();
    ...
}
```

#### Arquivo2

```
partial class form1 : Form {
     ...
     partial void InitializeComponent() {
           ...
     }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Partial.cs).