# Como criar uma janela sem usar o construtor de GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gui

Estou começando a estudar C# e assim como no Java, IDEs fornecem recursos que tornam possível construir GUIs facilmente arrastando componentes. O [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) possui uma poderosa ferramenta de construção onde é possível arrastar componentes Swing para um `JFrame`, `JDialog`, etc. No [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) me senti em casa, é praticamente o mesmo esquema.

A minha duvida é: No Netbeans, o código gerado pelo *GUI Builder* é funcional, porém muito complicado de dar manutenção - supondo que quem for dar manutenção não usará o construtor de interface do Netbeans (e.g um usuário do [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)). Dependendo dos requisitos na interface gráfica é muito melhor escrever o código "na unha", tornando o código fonte bem mais simples de ler. Não sei como o código da janela é gerado em C#, mas gostaria de saber se é possível construir uma interface gráfica no código "puro", manualmente.

Por exemplo, em Java basta o seguinte trecho para mostrar uma janela:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MinhaJanela extends JFrame {

    public MinhaJanela(){
        super("Minha Janela");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Click aqui");
        btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            btnClick();
        });
        getContentPane().add(btn);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void btnClick(){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clicou!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MinhaJanela();
    }
}
```

Como seria criar a mesma janela em `C#`?

---

**PS:** Não, eu não sou um *hater* de construtores de GUI, é mais por questão de curiosidade mesmo, quero entender como funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concordo que frequentemente é melhor escrever o código na mão que usar o gerador. Dá mais flexibilidade e controle. Eu sou *visual builder hater* :P

O Visual Studio gera códigos mais fáceis de dar manutenção separando inclusive o que você deve mexer e o que só o gerador deveria manipular (você até pode mexer nesta parte sob risco de criar dificuldades para o gerador). A existência de [métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44337/101) e [classes parciais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ajudam muito nisto.

Mas nada impede de escrever tudo na mão. O que eu vejo acontecer muito em programadores experientes que estão começando no C# é gerar um classe pelo IDE para analisar e ver como proceder em futuras implementações manuais.

Um Hello World um pouco mais funcional que o seu exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
public class HelloWorld : Form {
    static public void Main() {
        Application.Run(new HelloWorld());
    }
 
    public HelloWorld() {
        this.Text = "Minha Janela";
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "Click aqui";
        b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        Controls.Add(b);
    }
 
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicou!");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ConstructorLess.cs).

Um [tutorial mais completo](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31560).

Comment: Achei interessante (e estranho) a forma de adicionar um *listener* no botão: `b.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);` é quase um "concatenar" evento.

Comment: @renan e não deixa de ser uma concatenação. Ele concatena a uma lista de assinantes.